# What is nextprops in UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps and convert it into React Hook Functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am beginner in ReactJS , I am converting class components to functional.

```
    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let oldGroupList =
      (this.props.contentMultiaction && this.props.contentMultiaction.groups) || [];
    let newGroupList = nextProps.contentMultiaction?.groups || [];

    if (oldGroupList.length !== newGroupList.length) {
      this.getShownGroups(nextProps);
    }
    this.checkAllGroupsState(nextProps);
  }
```

Though this is a deprecated life cycle method, I wanted to knw how to rewrite it in functional component.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using useEffect() hook

Answer (score 0):

Use `useEffect()` hook. Add the values you want to watch to hook's dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 // runs if contentMultiaction.groups has changed
}, [contentMultiaction.groups]);
```

Comment: Can you help with whole code block?